# How to sort an associative array into alternative largest smallest order?

Tags: php, arrays

Does anyone know how to sort an associative array into alternating largest smallest values?

I.E.

```
array("A"=>10, "B"=>2, "C"=>5, "D"=>1, "E"=>30, "F"=>1, "G"=>7)
```

Should become:

```
array("E"=>30, "D"=>1, "A"=>10, "F"=>1, "G"=>7, "B"=>2, "C"=>5)
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any algorithm of sorting in the result example. Could you point to it, please?

Comment: I think largest,smallest,secondlargest,secondsmallest etc. etc.

Comment: Well what is the problem? First you sort the array ascending or descending, whatever, next you iterate over it and construct the output array in any order you want.

Comment: Huh? That's what I'm asking! How do I achieve it?

Comment: You iterate over a function whilst there are elements left in the sorted array. In each iteration you pop the last/first element from the array depending on if the key is even/uneven. That what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer to your previous version of this question:

```
$myArray = array("A"=>10, "B"=>2, "C"=>5, "D"=>1, "E"=>30, "F"=>1, "G"=>7);
asort($myArray);
$myArrayKeys = array_keys($myArray);

$newArray = array();
while (!empty($myArray)) {
    $newArray[array_shift($myArrayKeys)] = array_shift($myArray);
    if (!empty($myArray))
        $newArray[array_pop($myArrayKeys)] = array_pop($myArray);
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

or, if you want largest first:

```
$myArray = array("A"=>10, "B"=>2, "C"=>5, "D"=>1, "E"=>30, "F"=>1, "G"=>7);
asort($myArray);
$myArrayKeys = array_keys($myArray);

$newArray = array();
while (!empty($myArray)) {
    $newArray[array_pop($myArrayKeys)] = array_pop($myArray);
    if (!empty($myArray))
        $newArray[array_shift($myArrayKeys)] = array_shift($myArray);
}
var_dump($newArray);
```